# Reading from a file to a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

For my school, I am making an ATM. I have created the base of it with the functions: deposit, withdraw and check balance.
I have made it so the users are saved to a file "users" with their name, balance and pin. I can get it to write to the dictionary correctly and save to the file but when the code runs it doesn't read them in the order I need.

Code:

```
users = {}
pin = 0
balance = 0
with open("N:\users") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split() #Reads the file like ('Ben:[0,', 0): '1234]'
       users[key, pin] = val**
print users
```

This code above is taking the file and writing it to the dictionary, however it puts it in the dictionary wrong and I don't know how to fix it

```
def Login():
    if name in users:
        pin = raw_input("Enter your pin:")
        if pin == users[pin]:
            print "Welcome back", name
        else:
           print "Wrong pin"
    elif name == "join":
        bal = 0
        pcor = 0
        nname = raw_input("Welcome new user, enter your name.")
        while pcor != 1:
            npin = int(raw_input("Enter a 4 digit pin."))
            if len(str(npin)) != 4:
                print "Please enter another FOUR digit pin eg: 1234."
            else:
                pcor = 1
        users[nname] = [bal,npin] #Writes to dictionary: Ben:[0, 1234]
        print users
        with open("N:\users", 'a') as f:
            for key, val in users.items():
                f.write('{}:[{},{}]\n'.format(key, bal, npin)) #Saves to the file like I want: Ben:[0, 1234]. However When you add a new user, it saves all existing users again

    elif name == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        print "Unrecognised response."
        exit()

def Deposit():
   add = int(raw_input("How much would you like to deposit?"))
   users[key] = int(users[key]) + int(add)
   print "Your balance is now", users[key]
   f1 =open('N:\users', 'w+')
   print >> f1,name,users[key]
   f1.close()

def Withdraw():
   minus = int(raw_input("How much would you like to withdraw?"))
   if minus > int(users[key]):
      print "You do not have enough in your account."
   else:
      users[key] = int(users[key]) - int(minus)
      print "Your balance is now", users[key]
      f1 =open('N:\users', 'w+')
      print >> f1,name,users[key]
      f1.close()

def CheckFunds():
   print "You have £"+users[key], "in your account."

name = raw_input("If you are have an account, enter your name, \
if you would like to make an account enter 'join', \
if you want to exit the ATM type 'exit'.")
Login()
action = raw_input("What would you like to do? A)Deposit B)Withdraw C)Check Balance D)Exit")
if action == "a" or action == "A":
   Deposit()
elif action == "b" or action == "B":
   Withdraw()
elif action == "c" or action == "C":
   CheckFunds()
else:
   exit()
```

Thank you for any help, Ben.

Comment: What does your source file (`N:\users`) look like?

Comment: Just a file with some text, when you create a new user it saves like Ben:[0, 1234] and adds a new line for the next user

Comment: You might want to explain better what you expect and what you are getting. Dictionaries are not sorted in general. If you write out to a file it will append the content unless you use `open("N:\users", 'w')`. So if you loop everytime through the dictionary you will keep appending all the entries every time

Comment: I would like it to take the file per line which is writen like Name:[balance, pin] and put it in the dictionary like that. I need it so the key is the name, with two values, the balance and pin. It already saves it to the file like that when you create a new user, but I cant get it to read it like that.